# getJSON Twitter

Tags: twitter, getjson

Trying to get a tweet using JSON.  I have the tweet ID but nothing returns.  Any ideas?

Here is the code im using

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=204981356940369920", function(data) {
 $("#twitter").html(data[0].text);
```

});

Comment: Link to the site it's on? I would also do an alert(data[0].text) and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

That's returning JSON. Due to the [same-origin security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), you'll need to use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/).

So, the call needs to be

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=204981356940369920&callback=whatever
```

If you're using jQuery, you can use

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=204981356940369920&callback=?
```

And jQuery will automagically add the callback